# docker error elastic search image not accessible with the parameters provided by the setup file

Tags: linux, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elasticsearch-5

I have a clustered Env with docker swarm.
I upgraded elastic search image from 2.4 to 5.6 and now when I'm deploying my app, I get an error:

> ERROR: Validation failed: Elastic search not accessible with the parameters provided by the setup file. Hosts: nga_es, Port: 9300, Cluster name: elasticsearch. Error: None of the configured nodes are available.

I get the error from the second container which trying to connect to elastic search.

This is the `docker-compose.yml` file (version 3) I wrote: (the relevant lines to elastic):

```
 nga_es:
networks:
  octanet:
    aliases:
    - nga_es
environment: 
  ES_JAVA_OPTS: '-Xms4G -Xmx4G'
tty: true
image: elasticsearch:5.6
ports:
- 9300
- 9200
stdin_open: true
```

Does someone has a clue why I'm getting this error? I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read all the Docker Hub notes about that elasticsearch:5 image?

- It's being deprecated, best move to the [official es image](https://hub.docker.com/r/elastic/elasticsearch/).
- Did you [see the "cluster" notes](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/) about cluster setup and capabilities ES will need?